# How to handle escape sequence's in json string in mulesoft

Tags: json, mule

I have json input like this

```
{
    "receivedNumber": "\357425078",
    "receivedRma": "RL975F0718331133212",
    "EndDate": "12/16/2017 12:54:13 PM",
    "manufacturerDate": "11/14/2016",
    "firstUseDate": "12/17/2016 11:58:20 AM"
}
```

for this input, 'json to object transformer' getting failed because of escape sequence in 'receivedNumber'

is there any solution regarding this ? how to handle escape sequence ?

Comment: Have you already ried to escape the backslash? in json it is represented as special Character: \\  Backslash character => "\\357425078"

Comment: Can you provide the code that tries to read the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
"{ \"receivedNumber\": \"\357425078\", \"receivedRma\": \"RL975F0718331133212\", \"EndDate\": \"12/16/2017 12:54:13 PM\", \"manufacturerDate\": \"11/14/2016\", \"firstUseDate\": \"12/17/2016 11:58:20 AM\" }";
```